# Нужно проверить пустые ли строки. Выходит StringIndexOutOfBoundsException и тест выдает fail

Tags: java

```
public class PairsCharString {
    public static boolean check(String l, String r) {
        boolean rsl = false;
        char rslFirstL = l.charAt(0);
        char rslLastR = r.charAt(r.length() - 1);
        char rslLastL = l.charAt(l.length() - 1);
        char rslFirstR = r.charAt(0);
        if (l.isEmpty() && r.isEmpty()) {
            rsl = true;
        } else if ((rslFirstL == rslLastR) && (rslLastL == rslFirstR)) {
            rsl = true;
        }
        return rsl;
    }
}

public class PairsCharStringTest {

    @Test
    public void checkTrue() {
        boolean rsl = PairsCharString.check("", "");
        assertThat(rsl, is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkTrue1() {
        boolean rsl = PairsCharString.check("sparkling", "groups");
        assertThat(rsl, is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void checkFalse() {
        boolean rsl = PairsCharString.check("booking", "grabber");
        assertThat(rsl, is(false));
    }
}
```

Comment: что по-твоему должно выдать l.charAt(0), если строка пустая? Что вообще за странный метод проверки

Comment: @Эникейщик Строго не судите я только учусь программировать. Если строка пустая должно быть null. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: условие задачи: 1. Если обе строки пустые - метод должен вернуть true.

2. Если первая буква первой строки равна последней букве второй строки И последняя буква первой строки равна первой букве второй строки - метод должен вернуть true.

3. Во всех остальных случаях метод должен вернуть false.

Comment: Нет. Если строка пустая, то будет именно то, что происходит. У пустой строки длина равна 0 (это подсказка).

Comment: А, ну или там даже у вас есть isEmpty(). Нужно эту проверку делать в самом начале

Comment: @Эникейщик для чего делать проверку в самом начале?

Comment: Если оба строки пустые, то сразу возвращать true, если одна пустая, а вторая нет, то возвращать false. В третьем случае делать все остальное - это значит, что обе строки не пустые и такой ошибки будет.

Comment: и в следующий раз описывайте задачу и возникшую проблему точно, а то у вас задача одна, в заголовке другое, а ошибка вообще третья.

Comment: @Эникейщик а как в итоге код будет выглядить, не могу сообразить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обязательно измените класс `PairsCharString`:

```
public class PairsCharString {
    
    public static boolean check(String l, String r) {
        return l.isEmpty() && r.isEmpty() || // Если две строки пусты - true
                !(l.isEmpty() || r.isEmpty()) && // Если одна пустая, а другая нет - false
                 // Если первая буква первой строки равна последней букве второй строки и  последняя буква первой строки равна первой букве второй строки: 
                (l.charAt(0) == r.charAt(r.length() - 1)) && 
                (l.charAt(l.length() - 1) == r.charAt(0));
    }
    
}
```

---

Если все еще не работает, то измените класс `PairsCharStringTest` и на это:

```
public class PairsCharStringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean rsl1 = PairsCharString.check("", "");
        rsl1 = PairsCharString.check("", "1");
        System.out.println(rsl1);
        boolean rsl2 = PairsCharString.check("sparkling", "groups");
        System.out.println(rsl2);
        boolean rsl3 = PairsCharString.check("booking", "grabber");
        System.out.println(rsl3);
    }
}
```